# torbrowser signature verification fails - a glitch or an "attack"?

Tags: security, tor, signature

I wanted to try using TOR on my new Linux Mint 18.1 installation. So I `apt-get install`ed `torbrowser-launcher` and `tor`, then ran [`torbrowser-launcher`](https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher). It opened a dialog box and showed me it was downloading the TOR browser; but when it was done, it said it had failed the signature check and that I may be "under attack" (oh my!).

Now, it's quite unlikely I'm under some attack personally (I'm not important enough for that), so I'm guessing either it's some technical glitch, or, what would be possible although far far less likely, a man-in-the-middle attack covering my ISP rather than myself individually, nefarious government surveillance or what-not.

How can I tell? What should I do?

By the way, the URLs downloaded are:

https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/6.5/tor-browser-linux64-6.5_en-US.tar.xz.asc
https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/6.5/tor-browser-linux64-6.5_en-US.tar.xz

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### It's not an attack, just an outdated key.

There's a [issue report](https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher/issues/263) on this matter over at the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher/).

A workaround reported there, which works for some systems if not all, is to run:

```
gpg --homedir "$HOME/.local/share/torbrowser/gnupg_homedir/" --refresh-keys --keyserver pgp.mit.edu
```

before `torbrowser-launcher`. Then it works. It's quite possible that what Kusalananda suggested would also work, but I can't check that unless  I undo the key update.

Comment: Yes, you can undo the key update, just remove the key: `gpg --delete-key D1483FA6C3C07136`.

Comment: +1 Because (even if very useful) @Kusalananda check did not solve the issue. Only your recommended update of the correct (for torbrowser) trust database file did solve the issue.

Comment: As follows down in the issue, in case there's a problem with `pgp.mit.edu`, another keyserver may be used, eg. `pool.sks-keyservers.net`.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Linux Mint LMDE 2.

Answer (score 2):

When I download the the signature and the compressed archive, fetch the key from a keyserver, and verify the signature:

```
$ gpg2 --recv-key D1483FA6C3C07136
gpg: key 4E2C6E8793298290: public key "Tor Browser Developers (signing key) <torbrowser@torproject.org>" imported
gpg: marginals needed: 3  completes needed: 1  trust model: pgp
gpg: depth: 0  valid:   2  signed:   0  trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 2u
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1

$ gpg2 --verify tor-browser-linux64-6.5_en-US.tar.xz.asc
gpg: assuming signed data in 'tor-browser-linux64-6.5_en-US.tar.xz'
gpg: Signature made Tue Jan 24 15:42:49 2017 CET
gpg:                using RSA key D1483FA6C3C07136
gpg: Good signature from "Tor Browser Developers (signing key) <torbrowser@torproject.org>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: EF6E 286D DA85 EA2A 4BA7  DE68 4E2C 6E87 9329 8290
     Subkey fingerprint: A430 0A6B C93C 0877 A445  1486 D148 3FA6 C3C0 7136
```

So, the signature is good. I suggest that you try again, or investigate if this is the same issue as reported in the Tor Browser issue tracker ([issue 263](https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher/issues/263)).

How did I know what key to verify with?

I first ran the verification without fetching any key and got:

```
gpg: assuming signed data in 'tor-browser-linux64-6.5_en-US.tar.xz'
gpg: Signature made Tue Jan 24 15:42:49 2017 CET
gpg:                using RSA key D1483FA6C3C07136
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
```

Then I checked `D1483FA6C3C07136` against the key IDs listed on the Tor project's site and found that it was indeed the correct key: https://www.torproject.org/docs/signing-keys.html.en

This is, I believe, as close as I can get to knowing that the archive wasn't tampered with without meeting the developers face to face and having them personally hand me a USB stick with the software.

Comment: Where did you get the hex string `D1483FA6C3C07136`? It's not clear from your answer. Also, I found a(n about as simple) workaround.

Comment: @einpoklum I ran the verification first to see what key I was missing, then I fetched that key.  I also checked the web to make sure this was indeed the correct key. https://www.torproject.org/docs/signing-keys.html.en

Comment: I think maybe that should be part of the answer, so if people have a similar - but not exactly the same - problem, they'll understand what to do.

Comment: @einpoklum Sorted.

Comment: Thanks, your post is clear and helpful, but only when the trust database that torbrowser use (take a look at @einpoklum post) did I solve the same problem. Maybe you could include this idea for future readers. Again, thanks.

Comment: @sorontar Added link to github issue tracker post.

Comment: @Kusalananda - Everytime I download images or software via my Browser I generally wonder about the effectivness of this verification process. While this seems to be a sane way to ensure the origin of downloaded software and the steps you mentioned are the same I take to ensure the credibility of my downloads, this downgrades the whole chain of trust to the reliability of SSL/TLS certificate chains. An additional step could be to take a look at who trusted the fetched public key, but this does not solve the problem.