# Somehow, someway, gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found

Tags: gpg, tor

Trying to install tor through [this](https://itsfoss.com/install-tar-browser-linux/) websites guide. Working well, until I reach a `SIGNATURE VERIFICATION FAILED` error. They said to run this command to fix the key:

```
gpg --homedir "$HOME/.local/share/torbrowser/gnupg_homedir" --refresh-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com
```

Which falls into a `gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found` error. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338721/gpg-no-valid-openpgp-data-found) stackoverflow, but it contains a variety of nonspecific answers, all either concerning `wget` or `curl`. A similar issue was discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/341513/torbrowser-signature-verification-fails-a-glitch-or-an-attack/341519#341519), but the answer was this command, which is where I'm having trouble. I deleted and reset my `.gnupg` folder, but I still hit the same error for some reason. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The linked answer of the "[similar issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/341513/torbrowser-signature-verification-fails-a-glitch-or-an-attack/341519#341519)" actually features a slightly different command: It ends with the key server `pgp.mit.edu`, not with `keyserver.ubuntu.com`.

For me, it worked with this MIT key server.