# Tor Browser launcher quits immediately

Tags: ubuntu, tor

I tried to run Tor Browser, installed from the Ubuntu 20.04 official repository. First the browser just wouldn't start:

```
$ torbrowser-launcher 
Tor Browser Launcher
By Micah Lee, licensed under MIT
version 0.3.2
https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher
Your version of Tor Browser is out-of-date. Downloading the newest version.
Downloading https://aus1.torproject.org/torbrowser/update_3/release/Linux_x86_64-gcc3/x/en-US
$ echo $?
0
```

Then I tried to open the Tor Browser settings to see if there was anything I could do. I tried "Reinstall Tor Browser" and got [this output](https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher/issues/522):

```
$ torbrowser-launcher --settings
Tor Browser Launcher
By Micah Lee, licensed under MIT
version 0.3.2
https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher
Downloading Tor Browser for the first time.
Downloading https://aus1.torproject.org/torbrowser/update_3/release/Linux_x86_64-gcc3/x/en-US
Latest version: 10.0
Downloading https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/10.0/tor-browser-linux64-10.0_en-US.tar.xz.asc
Downloading https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/10.0/tor-browser-linux64-10.0_en-US.tar.xz
Verifying Signature
Refreshing local keyring...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/launcher.py", line 589, in verify
    c.verify(signature=sig, signed_data=signed)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpg/core.py", line 541, in verify
    raise errors.BadSignatures(results[1], results=results)
gpg.errors.BadSignatures: 110775B5D101FB36BC6C911BEB774491D9FF06E2: Key expired

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/launcher.py", line 600, in run
    verify()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/launcher.py", line 594, in verify
    raise Exception
Exception

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/launcher.py", line 603, in run
    self.common.refresh_keyring()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/common.py", line 196, in refresh_keyring
    p = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/gpg2', '--status-fd', '2',
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/bin/gpg2'
```

I solved the missing `/usr/bin/gpg2` with `sudo apt install gnupg2`. Several [posts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/341519/3645) suggest to run `gpg --homedir "$HOME/.local/share/torbrowser/gnupg_homedir/" --refresh-keys` to refresh the keys, but I still kept getting the same error message about the expired key. Looking at the [Tor Browser documentation](https://support.torproject.org/tbb/how-to-verify-signature/) I first tried `gpg --auto-key-locate nodefault,wkd --locate-keys torbrowser@torproject.org` and got the same result, then `gpg --homedir "$HOME/.local/share/torbrowser/gnupg_homedir/" --auto-key-locate nodefault,wkd --locate-keys torbrowser@torproject.org`.

At this point, trying to upgrade via `torbrowser-launcher --settings` results first in an error message:

> The version of Tor Browser you have installed is earlier than it should be, which could be a sign of an attack!

which seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher/issues/498) and then the installer gets stuck: [image: "Installing" dialogue]

**[Workaround](https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher/issues/498#issuecomment-697601953):** Run `~/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser` to start the new Tor Browser 10 directly.